# How To Get User Email From Cloud Identity Aware Proxy

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform

I want to build a web application in Go. I'm using Google App Engine for deployment combined with Identity Aware Proxy (IAP) to authenticate user access.

I want to know how to access the authentication to get the user email, which I can link to app data stored in a back end database. Essentially I want to avoid my users logging in and then having to authenticate again to get their profiles from the back end.

I have looked into the IAP documentation and I can see it uses JWT Headers and that is where my knowledge lacks. My guess would be a link to the incoming request which accesses those headers to get the email.

Comment: Process the `X-Goog-Authenticated-User-Email` HTTP header. https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/identity-howto

Comment: That was my conclusion, my question is probably misleading, as I don't know how to access the header using my programming language Go, and the framework I'm using Beego.

Comment: Rewrite your question so you get the answer you need.

Comment: https://beego.me/docs/mvc/controller/params.md

Comment: Ironically after looking at the links you have provided, I have found the answer thank you very much.

To access those JWT headers inside beego:
func (c *MainController) Get() {
 email:=c.Ctx.Request.Header.Get("X-Goog-Authenticated-User-Email")
 if  email == "" {
  email = "No Email Passed"
 }
 c.Data["Email"] = email
}

Comment: Create an answer with your code.